# I2C reading sequence head-scratching diagram

Tags: stm32, i2c, datasheet

I am using [MPU6500](https://www.glynstore.com/content/docs/invensense/PS-MPU-6500A-01.pdf) accelerometer in I2C mode. The datasheet explains the reading sequence on page 33:
[image]

It may seem easy for someone who is an expert, but it is my first time using the I2C interfaced device. I have written the following function, but it doesn't read register values like WHO_AM_I etc.

```c
uint8_t Accelerometer_Read(uint8_t reg)
{
    uint8_t read;

    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(accelerometerhandle, 0x68|0x00, &reg, 1, 100);
    HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(accelerometerhandle, 0x68|0x01, &read, 1, 100);

    return read;
}
```

I have connected AD0 to GND so that the I2C address is 0x68. How can I implement this sequence?

Comment: I think the problem here is that your master is likely issuing a stop condition after the first transmit, but the device is expecting a "repeated start" condition. Do you have a HAL_I2C function that supports repeated start conditions?

Comment: You mean there should be another S at the end of writing the register. Is it possible by sending dummy value like 0x00?

Comment: Use `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read()` instead. That will perform the correct sequence of Start-devAddr-regAddr-reStart-readData-Stop all for you.

Comment: The alternative would b to use interrupts. Start with a `HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Transmit_IT()`, then in the TxCplt callback do a `HAL_I2C_Master_Seq_Receive_IT()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the HAL_I2C_Mem_Read, that will do the standard "read from register address" sequence.